# Can't connect Appium in C#: error - the requested resource could not be found

Tags: c#, appium

I run my C# code on my laptop, it runs OK, but when I transfer program to my PC, it doesn't run. I installed Appium, Java, SDK on my PC, I run my code and get this error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource'

Here is my code:

```
public bool ConnectAppium()
{
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", this.Resutl("shell getprop ro.build.version.release").Replace("\r\n", ""));
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", this._driver);
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("systemPort", this._port + 4000);
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("udid", this._driver);
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("devicePort", this._port);
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("noReset", true);
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("disableWindowAnimation", true);
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("gpsEnabled", true);
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("skipLogcatCapture", true);
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("dontStopAppOnReset", true);
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("ignoreHiddenApiPolicyError", true);
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("noSign", false);
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", 36000);
                    string resutl = TLExecute.CMD("netstat -an |find /i \"listening\"");

                    bool flag = !resutl.Contains(this._port.ToString());

                    if (flag)
                    {
                        new Task(delegate ()
                        {
                            Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                            {
                                FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%") + "\\System32\\cmd.exe",
                                WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath,
                                Arguments = "/c appium --port " + this._port.ToString(),
                                CreateNoWindow = true,
                                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                UseShellExecute = false,
                                Verb = "runas",
                                RedirectStandardError = true
                            });
                            process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                        }).Start();

                        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
                            resutl = TLExecute.CMD("netstat -an |find /i \"listening\"");

                            bool flag2 = resutl.Contains(this._port.ToString());

                            if (flag2)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    this.remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:" + this._port.ToString() + "/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
                    this.remoteWebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);

                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
            return false;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what is TLExecute, rest is general stuff and somebody should be capable to help...

Comment: TLExecute is run adb as cmd bro

Comment: Thanks, I am used only to web/windows appium :)...